# Awesomium web view is not loading url

Tags: c#, webview, awesomium

I have an awesomium web view in a winform. The software was working fine until today when the web view is not loading the page even after setting the source property programmatically. When I move my cursor on top of the control it just shows the busy icon.

I have added a lot of other controls using devexpress (and the webview was working fine earlier with Devexpress as well).

I remade a test project with a devexpress ribbon and just the webview and the webview loaded fine.

Has anyone come across this issue and can shed light on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest deleting your current control of awesomium and re add it. If that doesn't work, delete it again and add that dll to the toolbox. The dll is located in program files or program files x86, under awesomium.